# Laravel 5.8 Multiple Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, admin, laravel-5.8

I am trying to create multiple authentication laravel 5.8. i have two tabels one is users and admins. i have configured the guards for admin. the admin login works fine if i use App\User::class but when i try to login through the App\Admin::class, the admin login doesn't work even if I login with correct credentials. Please help me to solve this problem.

this is my admin model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

This is my guard setting

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

This is my admin login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Route;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    // use AuthenticatesUsers;



    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/cpanel';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Show the admin login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('admin');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // validate the inputs
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8'
        ]);

        /* Check the guard is admin,
        and all credentials are matching with database records
        */ 
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
            // Credentials are matching
            // redirect the admin to cpanel
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.cpanel'));


        }
        // Credntials are not matching
        // redirect the admin to login page
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    // function for logout
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/admin/login');
    }

}
```

This is exception handler

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Auth; 

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */


    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {

        $guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(),0);

        switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
                $redirect = route('admin.login');
                break;

            default:
                $redirect = route('login');
                break;
        }

        return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                    : redirect()->guest($redirect);
    }

}
```

Comment: Replacing "$this->middleware('auth:admin')->except('logout');" instead of "        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');" works?

Comment: have you got any solution for this?